# How to translate attributes of table-less model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, active-attr

[RailsCast #326 ActiveAttr](http://railscasts.com/episodes/326-activeattr) explains how to create table-less models.

How can one translate the attributes as it is explained for table-based attributes in the [rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models)?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Translation.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Instead of** going via ActiveRecord (e.g. `de.activerecord.attributes.message.subject: Betreff`), ActiveModel has to be referenced (e.g. `de.activemodel.attributes.message.subject: Betreff`).

-- outlined by stephenmurdoch [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689730/contact-us-functionality-in-rails-3/3691310#comment14336116_3691310)